# Grub menu colors

Tags: grub2

I've set a Grub background image. And set other colors. Using [this tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/grub-splash-image/). To set the colors I've edited `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

Original

```
if [ -z "${2}" ] && [ -z "${3}" ]; then
        echo "  true"
fi
```

Into

```
if [ -z "${2}" ] && [ -z "${3}" ]; then
        echo "  true"
        echo "    set menu_color_highlight=light-cyan/cyan"
        echo "    set menu_color_normal=white/black"
        echo "    set color_normal=white/black"
fi
```

First off this feels wrong editing such a *core* file. Can I put this somewhere else, if so where/how?

If not. How could I automate putting these lines in?
I'm trying to create a script that will auto install the complete grub. I got the rest working like:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=2/' /etc/default/grub
```

But I can't get it to work with these lines. If possible I would like to mess with line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for Custom Theme Installation:

1. Create a folder named `themes` in `~/Downloads`
2. Create a sub folder named `TestTheme` in `~/Downloads/themes/`
3. Create a `theme.txt` file in  `~/Downloads/themes/TestTheme/`
4. Copy this file into https://we.tl/t-sUYtYqVjmT `~/Downloads/themes/TestTheme/`
5. Copy and Paste the below Content in  `~/Downloads/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt` file which we already created.

content:

```
# Global properties
title-text: "Hi Welcome to my Customized Grub"
#desktop-image: "background.png"
desktop-color: "#ff66c1"
terminal-left: "0"
terminal-top: "0"
terminal-width: "100%"
terminal-height: "100%"
terminal-border: "0"

# Boot menu
+ boot_menu {
  left = 15%
  top = 20%
  width = 70%
  height = 60%
  item_color = "#a1d0d0"
  selected_item_color = "#cc0000"
  item_height = 40
  item_spacing = 10
}

# Countdown message
+ label {
  left = 0
  top = 98%-20
  width = 100%
  align = "center"
  id = "__timeout__"
  text = "Booting in %d seconds"
  color = "#f2de15"
}

# Navigation keys hint 
+ label {
  left = 0
  top = 98%-60
  width = 100%
  align = "center"
  text = "Use arrow keys to select OS and Press Enter"
  color = "#456789"
}
```

Now we have required things for Creating Theme
[image]

6. Now Create a Script named InstallGT.sh in `~/bin/` with following

content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: InstallGT.sh
# PATH: ~/bin/
# DESC: Install Grub Theme
# DATE: Nov 11th 2018

sed -i "\$aGRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt" /etc/default/grub
cp -r ~/Downloads/themes /boot/grub/
update-grub
```

7. make the script executable with the command:
   `chmod +x ~/bin/InstallGT.sh`
8. Now run the command to install Grub Theme:
   `sudo ~/bin/InstallGT.sh`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-6550U:~$ sudo ~/bin/InstallGT.sh
[sudo] password for pratap: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (18.04) on /dev/sda10
Found Ubuntu 18.10 (18.10) on /dev/sda8
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
pratap@i7-6550U:~$
```

Reboot to See the Installed Grub Theme.

[image]

We have 5 colors those are in line numbers 4, 17, 18, 31 & 41 in `theme.txt` file. To change those colors edit the colors in below commands and run each command separately.

```
sudo sed -i 4d /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt && sudo sed -i '4idesktop-color: "#0acff9"' /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
sudo sed -i 17d /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt && sudo sed -i '17iitem_color = "#120af9"' /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
sudo sed -i 18d /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt && sudo sed -i '18iselected_item_color = "#00FF00"' /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
sudo sed -i 31d /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt && sudo sed -i '31icolor = "#G6G6G6"' /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
sudo sed -i 41d /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt && sudo sed -i '41icolor = "#LLLLLL"' /boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt
```

I have changed colors in line number 4 & 17 and gave those 2 commands and rebooted.

[image]

***How to go back to Normal: ***

1. `sudo rm -rf /boot/grub/themes`
2. `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and delete the last line which contains `GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/theme.txt`
3. `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, but that does not answer my question. I know how to edit it. But I want to know is there a way to do it _without_ touching a default file. And can I automate it in bash. I don't want to open an editor. And edit lines manually.

Comment: If you don't want to edit the default one, the alternative is to install grub themes which other answer suggests and once installed make required changes to that theme so that default theme is undisturbed. Thanks.

Comment: @janw i have edited the answer to give an example of custom theme. Thanks

Comment: I laughed when I saw the default colors. This is exactly what I needed. the `pf2` file is a font right?

Comment: Yes. It's font. You can use any pf2 font.

Comment: I figured, just checking. This is all I need.

Comment: If you want background.. Remove the # sign in line no. 3 in `themes.txt` file and give the correct name of file. file should be placed in `/boot/grub/themes/TestTheme/` folder

Answer (score 1):

You can get new grub2 themes here:

https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/109/

As far as changing colors. I don't know anything about that.